# Javers: restore previous version of bean

Tags: java, javers

is it possible to "checkout" a specific commit or version/snapshot of an object?
I mean: I done some changes on my bean, then committed the object through Javers utilities, but I want to checkout a previous version because actual version is corrupted or incorrect.
Is there a Javers utility to "restore" previous data? Or do I have to restore the object reverting single changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we call it Shadows. Shadows will be released soon in 3.2.0.
You can check it out in 3.2.0-RC4:

For example, to get latest Shadows of "bob" Person, call:

```
List<Shadow> shadows =
javers.findShadows( QueryBuilder.byInstanceId("bob", Person.class).limit(5).build() );
```

Since Shadows are instances of your domain classes, you can use them directly in your application:

```
assert shadows.get(0).get() instanceof Person.class;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, it is what I was looking for! Is it also possible to make queries on shadows?
When 3.2.0 will be released (more or less)?

Comment: 3.2.0 should be released till the end of May. You can read the doc about Shadows on this branch https://github.com/javers/javers.github.io/blob/shadows/documentation/jql-examples/index.md#querying-for-shadows

Comment: Thanks a lot again!

Comment: 3.2.0 is released, see http://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#query-for-shadows